# PHP is inserting question marks to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8

I am trying to INSERT an row to MySQL database like this :

```
function insertUserRating($username, $eventid, $ratingval, $ratingtext) {
        mysqli_query($this -> db -> connect(), "SET NAMES 'utf8';");
        $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $query = mysqli_query($this -> db -> connect(), "   INSERT INTO  `rating` ( `id_user` ,`id_event` ,`rating_value` ,`rating_text` ,`rating_date`) 
            VALUES ((SELECT id_user FROM user WHERE username=  '$username' ),  '$eventid',  '$ratingval',  '$ratingtext',  '$datetime' )");
        if ($query) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

the connect function is like this :

```
public function connect() {
        require_once 'config.php';
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        $con -> set_charset("utf8");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
         throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno());}
        return $con;
    }
```

But still if I try to insert row with  `$ratingtext` having some unicode characters for example : Lepšišie I only get `Lepieie` in the table. Table has `utf8_slovak_ci` coding.

Comment: First of all put '$this -> db -> connect()' into a variable and use that variable to avoid unnecessary confusions

Comment: he did put it in a variable. 'db' is an instance field in his main class, and connect() is a function within his db class

Comment: Careful with SQL Injection... Use prepared statements or  parameterized queries

Comment: @XOOLOOO -have you printed $ratingtext to the screen to see what it contains prior to being inserted to your database? i think your problem is the string is getting messed up before you do your encoding (by that i mean the parameter has already had the foreign characters replaced

Comment: Try not doing this $ratingtext = utf8_encode($ratingtext); and not doing this    $con -> set_charset("utf8"); they shouldn't be needed if you have the charset type of the table set to the charset you need

Comment: $con -> set_charset("utf8"); Ignore this. Could destroy your data.

Comment: I tryied putting echo right after function header `function insertUserRating($username, $eventid, $ratingval, $ratingtext) { echo $ratingtext ... ` and it displayed nice but in the mysql it now states  only `Lep` in the newly inserted row I deleted all ` $con -> set_charset("utf8");` and `$ratingtext = utf8_encode($ratingtext); ` stuff ...

Answer (score 0):

The php module in mysql can't set itself to utf8 automatically based on the configurations. Probably nobody knows, why. The workaround is a

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

query at the beginning of every mysql connection.

I see in your question, that you are playing around with this bug already. No, you don't need `utf8_encode` and such tricks after you set this up.

Alternative things (`$something->connect` and like) won't work, they all are based on the mysql module of the php, which is a module of the apache. It is an old bug, which probably won't be ever repaired. Good luck!

Comment: SET NAMES 'utf8'; into mysql query ? like `mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");  `? and yea I figgured that stuff with connect() call but nwm, I have it in too many places now to rebuild this

Comment: Yes. It doesn't get any data, it only instructs mysql to communicate in an utf8-encoded data connection. Normally it should be handled automatically, only mysql module in php can't do it.

Comment: Before connection ? Where should I put this ... I am kinda confussed now

Comment: @XOOLOOO No. Just after the connection! But before the first query.

Comment: `mysqli_query( set names 'utf8' )` after `$con = mysqli_`

Comment: I have updated the question take a look on the first function if I am getting you right, I have updated it in that way but still getting only `Lep ` in row

Comment: @XOOLOOO Dave has also right. Now you should check if the string in your database is also utf-8, probably not. Simplest way to test it with a mysql client on an utf8-system.

Comment: Charset in MySQL: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) as from phpmyadmin. @Dave I added it still only `Lep` after inserting, as it is our schools server I can only access it viac phpadmin

Comment: @XOOLOOO Phpmyadmin also doesn't have this fix, you should use the commandline mysql client on an utf8 system, or enter this query in the main phpmyadmin.ini .

Comment: that, might be tricky, but if I insert row via phpmyadmin with special characters I get it right ... but kinda odd still, like 3 months ago I was running different php project and by just setting `$con->set_charset("utf8"); ` worked ...

Comment: Because none of your phpmyadmin and your system is running utf8. If you tried some char out of iso1 and iso2 you seen atthe moment that it doesn't work. And $con->set_charset does the same as my command.